# Best way to write text on an image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I am wanting to take a little calendar image and write the date and month on it.  This will be displayed many times in a list view, so I am looking for the optimum way to do it.

Below works great, is there a better way:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
try {
    // Load the png image into a bitmap
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.calendar_empty);
    // Have to copy the bitmap so it is mutable
    mBitmap = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    // Create a canvas from the bitmap to draw on
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(12);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawText("Sept", 11, 26, paint);
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    canvas.drawText("29", 14, 42, paint);
    // Display the results on the screen
    image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), mBitmap));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just take the ImageView, and put a TextView on it as an overlay for the title, inside a layout container that enables this - e.g. RelativeLayout or FrameLayout?

I had several projects in which I wrote titles on images this way, there were no problems with this approach.

Comment: With the overlay method do you have to get the density of the display and scale all of your calculations accordingly?  With the above method the android system sizes the image automatically.

Comment: Do you mean if the text's physical size in the TextView widget remains the same across devices with different screen densities? If so, then yes, TextView takes care of that, you can define the textSize in dip.

Comment: That and the location of the text on the image view.  For example a 100px x 100px image may be 70px or 150px depending on the density of the screen.  I will want to position my text X,Y pixels over and it be perfectly aligned across all resolutions.

Comment: You could just use RelativeLayout as the container, define the ImageView inside it first, TextView second, align both of them to the parent's left and top border and set a proper left and top margin of X, Y on the TextView.